# High CPU consumption issue while Tomcat was configured as windows service

Tags: java, tomcat

I have deployed one java application in tomcat server. And tomcat server was configured as windows service in one of my VMs. 
Our VMs are windows servers with 64GB RAM and 8 core 2.4 GHz Intel Xeon Processors. 
Below are the software details and JVM args configured.

1. JDK 1.7.0_67
2. Tomcat 7.0.90 
   JVM args for Tomcat : 
   -Xms2g -Xmx40g -XX:PermSize=1g -XX:MaxPermSize=2g

But still getting this issue, could you please any one help.

Comment: Can you be more explicit about `still getting this issue`? `High CPU consumption` is quite vague: any figures? any threshold? Also, have you tried some JVM monitoring tool such as [Visual VM](https://visualvm.github.io/) ?

Comment: Yes I tried to run the Visual VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable **JMX** (which is a technology to monitor java applications) by adding the `-Dcom.sun.management .....` jvm options on the startup script and connect your application via **JConsole with JTop Plugin** which shows the top CPU consuming threads. Refer :https://arnhem.luminis.eu/top-threads-plugin-for-jconsole/